# Prove this generates the kth permutation in a lexicographically sorted list

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm working with a graph problem and found some code online that gives me correct results, but I am not sure how to mathematically prove its soundness.

How can I prove that the algorithm below does, indeed, give the k$^{th}$ lexicographically ordered permutation of a list?

```
def kth_perm(L, k):

    # P is our new list
    P = []

    # While L is not empty             
    while L:
        # Compute the factorial
        f = factorial(len(L)-1)

        i = int(floor(k/f))
        x = L[i]
        k = k%f

        # Append to the new list the element at L's int(floor(k/factorial(len(L)-1))) index
        P.append(x)

        # Remove element at L[i] from the list
        L = L[:i] + L[i+1:] 
    return P
```

Sorry if this is out of place - I'd be happy to move it to a more appropriate community.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code? You try to retrieve the length of $S$ before it is even defined.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish I changed `S` to `L` but forgot to change it everywhere... should be good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove that it produces the k$^{th}$ permutation because you haven't defined a numbering of the permutations; but you can prove by induction that it produces a different permutation of $L$ for each $k$ with $0\le k\lt |L|!$: If two values of $k$ lead to different values of $i$, then the corresponding permutations differ in the first element. If not, they lead to different values of $k$ in the next iteration, so you can apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: The numbering of permutations is based on lexicographical ordering, but the answer is still valid.

Comment: @erip: Ah, the perils of relying on the title to complete the question...

Comment: I can't tell if this is glib or not, but I appreciate the answer nonetheless.